# Opening the front facing camera

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-camera2

I am stuck with the problem of not being able to make the user open up the front facing camera by default.

I am wondering if there is any semi straight forward way of doing this, whether that is using the Camera2 API, using Intent, or even a third party API.

I dont want to store the photo on the users phone as I am transferring it in to a bitmap and then in to a 64bit string to store remotely.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: cameraConfig.setCameraId(1) for Camera and Camera2 API by Intent for intent it should be like intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1) but by intent the user can simple turn the camera the other way around

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I have tried with the put extra, but it doesnt seem to make any difference, the camera will still start with the rear camera.

Comment: Intent cameraIntent = newIntent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);                      cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

Comment: To use the Camera2 API you need to attach the preview to a SurfaceView, its a lot more work, not sure how to sucessfully tell (any) camera application by intent to use the front camera (since it can be ignored by 3rd camera apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent to use default camera app using startActivityForResult().

Or you can use this library https://github.com/CameraKit/camerakit-android.

Or this one https://github.com/RedApparat/Fotoapparat.

Naturally, original Camera API (version 1) is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
mCamera = Camera.open(1); // for front camera

mCamera = Camera.open(0); // for Rear camera
```

And don't forget to add these permissions in your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"    android:required="false" />
```

Comment: I have tried this but it is telling me that the camera API is redundant. And when I run the app, nothing happens.

Comment: Alternatively you can try this : Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Uri photoUri = Uri.fromFile(getOutputPhotoFile());
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);